# SSE Spring Cloud Stream supplier

Tags: spring-integration, server-sent-events, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I'm trying to create a SSE Spring Cloud Stream supplier using the following code:

```kotlin
    @Bean
    fun sseSupplier(sseSupplierPub: Publisher<Message<Any>>): Supplier<Flux<Message<Any>>> {
        return Supplier {
            Flux.from(sseSupplierPub)
        }
    }

    @Bean
    fun sseSupplierPub(
        sseSupplierProperties: sseSupplierProperties
    ): Publisher<Message<Any>> {
        return IntegrationFlow.from(channelsConfiguration.trigger())
            .enrichHeaders {
                it.header(CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json")
                it.header(ACCEPT, "text/event-stream")
            }
            .handle(sseMessageHandlerSpec())
            .log()
            .toReactivePublisher(true)
    }

    fun webClient(): WebClient {
        val client = HttpClient.create(provider)
            .keepAlive(true)

        val clientRegistryRepo = InMemoryReactiveClientRegistrationRepository(
            ClientRegistration
                .withRegistrationId("clientId")
                .tokenUri("https://openid-connect/token")
                .clientId("clientId")
                .clientSecret("clientSecret")
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
                .build())
        val clientService = InMemoryReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService(clientRegistryRepo)
        val authorizedClientManager =
            AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(clientRegistryRepo, clientService)
        val oauthFilter = ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(authorizedClientManager)
        oauthFilter.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("clientId")

        return WebClient.builder()
            .filter(oauthFilter)
            .clientConnector(ReactorClientHttpConnector(client))
            .exchangeStrategies(strategies)
            .build()
    }

    fun sseMessageHandlerSpec(): WebFluxMessageHandlerSpec {
        return WebFlux.outboundGateway(
            "https://api/src", webClient())
            .httpMethod(HttpMethod.POST)
            .replyPayloadToFlux(true)
            .expectedResponseType(typeReference<ServerSentEvent<String>>())
    }

    @Bean
    fun commandLineRunner(ctx: ApplicationContext?): CommandLineRunner {
        return CommandLineRunner { _ ->
            val message = MessageBuilder.withPayload("{}").build()
            logger.info { "Trigger SSE supplier" }
            channelsConfiguration.trigger().send(message)
        }
    }
```

I'm able to get the authorisation token and connected to `https://api/src` successfully but I'm not able to get any response except for this message

```json
{
    "scanAvailable": true,
    "prefetch": -1
}
```

when I'm connected. After receiving the above message, I will not receive any more messages. What could be the problem?

Comment: Are you sure that it has to be `.httpMethod(HttpMethod.POST)` for receiving SSE? Would be also great to come up with something what we could reproduce locally. This way we could debug the problem and give some advises or even fixes.

Comment: Yes, it has to be POST to receive SSE. I  have another implementation using https://github.com/launchdarkly/okhttp-eventsource and it’s working. I’m trying to migrate that implementation to use spring cloud stream

Comment: Consult with your `https://api/src` provider to see if there is some info in their logs about your request to determine what might be missed or what is extra.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to receive data but I need to subscribe to `body` in the response (see the updated code below). The problem I'm facing now is how to map DataBuffer to ServerSentEvent.

```kotlin
    @Bean
    fun sseSupplier(sseSupplierPub: Publisher<Message<Any>>): Supplier<Flux<Message<Any>>> {
        return Supplier {
            Flux.from(sseSupplierPub)
        }
    }

    @Bean
    fun sseSupplierPub(
        sseSupplierProperties: sseSupplierProperties
    ): Publisher<Message<Any>> {
        return IntegrationFlow.from(channelsConfiguration.trigger())
            .enrichHeaders {
                it.header(CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json")
                it.header(ACCEPT, "text/event-stream")
            }
            .handle(sseMessageHandlerSpec())
            .channel(channelsConfiguration.sseMessage())
            .log()
            .toReactivePublisher(true)
    }

    fun webClient(): WebClient {
        val client = HttpClient.create(provider)
            .keepAlive(true)

        val clientRegistryRepo = InMemoryReactiveClientRegistrationRepository(
            ClientRegistration
                .withRegistrationId("clientId")
                .tokenUri("https://openid-connect/token")
                .clientId("clientId")
                .clientSecret("clientSecret")
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
                .build())
        val clientService = InMemoryReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService(clientRegistryRepo)
        val authorizedClientManager =
            AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(clientRegistryRepo, clientService)
        val oauthFilter = ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(authorizedClientManager)
        oauthFilter.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("clientId")

        return WebClient.builder()
            .filter(oauthFilter)
            .clientConnector(ReactorClientHttpConnector(client))
            .exchangeStrategies(strategies)
            .build()
    }

    fun sseMessageHandlerSpec(): WebFluxMessageHandlerSpec {
        return WebFlux.outboundGateway(
            "https://api/src", webClient())
            .httpMethod(HttpMethod.POST)
            .bodyExtractor { inputMessage, _ ->
                inputMessage.body.subscribe {
                    val bytes = ByteArray(it.readableByteCount())
                    it.read(bytes)
                    DataBufferUtils.release(it)
                    val output = String(bytes)

                    val message = MessageBuilder.withPayload(output).build()
                    logger.debug { "SSE message payload => ${message.payload}" }
                    channelsConfiguration.sseMessage().send(message)
                }
            }
    }

    @Bean
    fun commandLineRunner(ctx: ApplicationContext?): CommandLineRunner {
        return CommandLineRunner { _ ->
            val message = MessageBuilder.withPayload("{}").build()
            logger.info { "Trigger SSE supplier" }
            channelsConfiguration.trigger().send(message)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Consider that your original question might be important to someone else.  Your answer doesn't specify (except perhaps through differences in the code) how you managed to receive data.  Additionally, your new question might also be of use to others, and perhaps it should be a new question.